# Efficient access to a Turtle's variable which is a patch address, or How to filter patches that are not assigned to turtles?

Tags: netlogo

In my simulation each turtle has a my-home variable which is the patch agent family lives in, so agents with same Family-ID have same my-home until one of agents moves out or family grows to more than 7 agents.

when an agent wants to move out , I have to check if there is any patch nearby which is not another's agent my-home, what I have done is to store all my-homes in a list and check if any selected possible next home is not a member of this list, but I believe there should be better way to do this:

```
let all-homes [my-home] of agents with [belongs_to = BS]
set my-home  min-one-of patches with [not member? self all-homes and label_ = BS][distance m]
```

- m is current home address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min-one-of patches with ...` assesses every patch in the entire world before picking a winner. That's going to be slow. I'd suggest searching nearby patches first, then farther patches, and so forth. Most of the time the turtle will find a new home after only a very brief search, so you'll have replaced code that's O(n) in the number of patches with code that's O(1)-ish. That should fix the main performance problem with this code.

The simplest such search routine I can think of is for the turtle to simply head in a random direction and keep moving `fd 1` until it lands on a free patch. But if you want to do something more rigorous that always results in finding the closest possible new home, you could do that too; you'll just have more code to write.

Building the `all-homes` list is probably only a secondary performance problem here, but it's fixable too. The simplest fix I can think of is to add:

```
patches-own [home?]
```

initialize it with `ask patches [ set home? false ]`, and then make sure that whenever a turtle adopts a patch as its home, it does `ask my-home [ set home? true ]`. Now you can replace `member? self all-homes` with simply `home?`. After all, you don't really need to know what all of the home patches are; you only need to know whether some particular patch is a home patch.

Comment: i will try it with home? variable, but do you think if I attach agents who live in each patch to that patch by a for example a patch variable which includes a list of all agents who set their homes to that patch I will introduce more complexity ? in that case I only need a patch with an empty who-lives-here variable